# Meteor Querying other users by email

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to query users by emails with the following command
`Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': 'me@example.com'});`

It works in the mongo shell but it returns undefined in Meteor.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Turned out that I'm not able to query other users. The same query works when I query the logged in user email.
So the question now how can I query on all the users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, Meteor only publishes the logged in user and you can, as you mention, run queries against that user. In order to access the other users you have to publish them on the server:

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

And subscribe to them on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
```

Also keep in mind that you might not want to publish all the fields so you can specify what fields you like to publish/not publish:

```
return Meteor.users.find({}, 
{
     // specific fields to return
     'profile.email': 1,
     'profile.name': 1,
     'profile.createdAt': 1
});
```

Once you have published the collection, you can run queries and access information for all the users.

Comment: This was it. I was following the parties example and didn't realize they published this but they called it 'directory'. Thanks!

Comment: so after subscribing, can i access the collection as `Meteor.users.find({'profile.isAdmin':true}).toArray();`

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful:

```
 var text = "me@example.com";
 Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': {$regex:text,$options:'i'}});
```

Also see [Advance Queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)

Comment: Your regex doesn't work for users with email addresses such as `bob+1@example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to publish the users as mentioned above answer and run the following command

```
Meteor.users.find({"emails": "me@example.com"}).fetch()
```

OR

```
Meteor.users.find({"emails.0": "me@example.com"}).fetch()
```

Comment: As Meteor puts by default login e-mail in array with field 'address', just added the following and it works like charm:
'''Meteor.users.findOne({"emails.0.address": "me@example.com"})'''  (after having published all users, with limited declared fields for security as mentioned above, then subscribing).