# Cannot access other users' email addresses in Meteor app

Tags: meteor

Before I begin, I have followed the steps here:  [Meteor Querying other users by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563980/meteor-querying-other-users-by-email)

And I have read the Meteor documentation about publishing users and how to add more fields than the id, username, and profile.  My situation exists in spite of all of these things.

I'm trying to access other user's email addresses, beyond just the currently logged in user.  I have 2 templates that need this access.  The first template works and is able to access it.  The second template is unable to.

Here is the setup code I have for publishing the emails field, and subscribing (I've also tried not specifying 'address' [e.g. fields: {emails: 1}] but that has the same result)

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("allUsers", function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({});
    });
    Meteor.publish("allUserData", function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {"emails.address": 1}});
    });
};

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("allUsers");
    Meteor.subscribe("allUserData");
};
```

Here is the code from the template that works:

```
Template.createPartner.events({
    'click .setup-partner' : function(event, template) {
        var partner = Meteor.users.findOne({"emails.address": 'example@mail.com' }); <-- works
    }
});
```

Here is the code from the template that doesn't work:

```
Template.infoSelect.partnerEmail = function() {
    var partnerId = Meteor.user().profile.partnerId; <-- works
    var partner = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: partnerId}); <-- works but only _id and profile are returned
    return partner.emails[0].address; <-- throws exception because the 'emails' field doesn't exist
};
```

I've also tried this, but no difference:

```
var partner = Meteor.users.find({_id: partnerId}, {fields: {"emails.address": 1}});
```

Why can I not see the user's email address in the second template, but I can in the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its because you're subscribing to two sets of the same collection. Meteor uses the first subscription and ignores the second. I'm not sure why it works on one occasion though.

If you remove the first subscription and go with the second It should work, basically remove the line:

```
Meteor.subscribe("allUsers");
```

One more tip. You could alter your email function to:

```
Template.infoSelect.partner = function() {
    var partnerId = Meteor.user().profile.partnerId; <-- works
    var partner = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: partnerId}); <-- works but only _id and profile are returned
    return partner;
};
```

And your handlebar would be : (it just opens up more options for your partner variable so you could reference him/her by name too)

```
<template name="infoSelect">
{{partner.email.0.address}}
{{partner.profile.name}} <!--If you have configured profiles -->
</template>
```

Comment: Oh yea, that's a great tip, thanks!  However, I've already tried your first suggestion of only subscribing/publishing once, and it didn't make any difference...

Comment: Wow!  Your second suggestion made it work!  I had already tried the first one, but when I modified to use the second one, it worked!  You my friend, are BRILLIANT!

Comment: I'm confused about creating a subscription called "allUsers".  If the subscription is called "allUsers", doesn't that create a Meteor Collection with the name "allUsers"?  If so, how does the "allUsers" collection get linked to the Meteor.users collection?  It seems like, once creating the "allUsers" subscription, I should have to then do my mongo queries on the new "allUsers" collection, instead of the Meteor.users collection, but that's not what's happening, so it's kind of confusing...

Comment: Keep in mind the subscription name and collection name are two different things. If you subscribe to something, the publish function for that subscription will send a copy of that collection down. So.. meteor.users and allUsers (by your subscription above) will contain the same data. For a better explanation in video check out : http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-subscriptions-and-ddp. The DDP may not be of much interest but he structure is explained very well.

Comment: Accessing arrays now looks like {{partner.emails.[0].address}}, at least with Meteor 1.0 (for anyone stumbling across this via google search as I did)