# meteor.js : find users by email

Tags: meteor

In my meteor.js app, I'm trying to write a simple admin page which can find a user by his/her email address.

I can see that in the Meteor.users collection there is an 'emails' array, which has objects like so

```
{ address : 'foo@foo.com',
  verified : false
}
```

Normally in Mongodb I can search inside this 'emails' array like so :

```
Meteor.users.find({ emails.address : 'foo@foo.com' });
```

But this query is throwing an error :

```
While building the application:
client/admin.js:224:41: Unexpected token .
```

Aka Meteor doesn't like the nested query...

Any ideas on how to query the Meteor.users collection by email address ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If on the server, Meteor has a special function for this :
[Accounts.findUserByEmail(email)](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-findUserByEmail).

I believe this is the recommended way.

Answer (score 57):

You can also use what you had, just put it in quotes:

```
Meteor.users.find({ "emails.address" : 'foo@foo.com' });
```

Comment: You can use `Meteor.users.findOne`, because we are looking for one single user.

Comment: It might be worth noting that Meteor's `Accounts.findUserByEmail(email)` makes a point to notice when there are multiple emails matching a provided email address. 

I don't know how that's possible, other than severe database malformation, but Meteor seems to think it's a significant enough use case to watch.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-findUserByEmail

Comment: This solution does not account for potential case mismatches. Accounts.findUserByEmail(email) does.

Answer (score 18):

Emails holds an array of emails.  Each email has an address.

Try `{ emails: { $elemMatch: { address: "foo@foo.com" } } }`.

Information on `$elemMatch` is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

Information on emails as an array is [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users).

Comment: thanks! this worked perfectly. strange the docs say explicitly that $elemMatch is not available on the client...

Answer (score 3):

By default, Meteor only publishes the logged in user and you can, as you mention, run queries against that user. In order to access the other users you have to publish them on the server:

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

And subscribe to them on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
```

And run the following command

```
Meteor.users.find({"emails": "me@example.com"}).fetch()
```

OR

```
Meteor.users.find({"emails.0": "me@example.com"}).fetch()
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563980/meteor-querying-other-users-by-email/31447395#31447395)

Comment: I've spent so long trying to figure out what is going on.  Am I an idiot or is it really just not that clear?

Comment: And apologies for being unclear - I meant about "Meteor only publishes the logged in user and you can" - it seems really misleading to name something `Meteor.users` and have it never return more than the logged in user.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find all emails inside Accounts array, and do an insensitive query:

```
const hasUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
    emails: {
      $elemMatch: {
        address: {
          $regex : new RegExp(doc.email, "i")
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround, if this works on the server but not the client, is to use a `users_by_email` method on the server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        'get_users_by_email': function(email) {
            return Users.find({ emails.address: email }).fetch();
        }
    });
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    foo_users = Meteor.call('get_users_by_email', 'foo@bar.baz');
}
```

Comment: Don't forget put email object on quotes